# Trying to create a minimax algorithm for a tic tac toe game, but I keep getting an nil value in a for loop

Tags: lua, minimax

I have made a post a few days ago, about trying to make a minimax algorithm but I didn't understand it at the time and I got told to go slowly through the tutorial I was using and try to make sure I understood, that is what I am doing now, I am going through each piece of code and making sure it prints the correct values and make sure it actually works.

So the issue I am having with is this part of the code

```
    local allTestPlayInfos = {}

for i = 1, size_of_array do
    local currentTestPlayInfo = {}
    local index = avaliable_slots[i]
    board[index] = current_player
    if current_player == "O" then
        local x_result = minimax(board,"X")
        currentTestPlayInfo["score"] = x_result["score"]
    else
        local o_result = minimax(board,"O")
        currentTestPlayInfo["score"] = o_result["score"] --This line
    board[index] = " "
    currentTestPlayInfo["index"] = index
    table.insert(allTestPlayInfos,i,currentTestPlayInfo)
    end
    _draw_board()
end
```

I am not sure why but at THIS LINE it keeps producing a nil value, that shouldnt be the case as the functions at the top should catch when the board becomes full but it doesnt, im not sure why, I have done everything else correctly to my knowladge, can someone give some in sight on why it keeps returning a nil value.
(https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/minimax-algorithm-guide-how-to-create-an-unbeatable-ai/)

Here is the full code, please copy and paste it and try it out.

```
local board_data = {top_L= " ", top_M = " ", top_R= " ", mid_L= " ", mid_M= " ", mid_R= " ", low_L= " ", low_M= " ",
low_R= " "}

local location = {"top","mid","low"}
local position = {"_L","_M","_R"}

local function _draw_board() -- Draws the games table
    print(
    board_data["top_L"].."┃"..board_data["top_M"].."┃"..board_data["top_R"].."\n"..
    "------\n"..
    board_data["mid_L"].."┃"..board_data["mid_M"].."┃"..board_data["mid_R"].."\n"..
    "------\n"..
    board_data["low_L"].."┃"..board_data["low_M"].."┃"..board_data["low_R"].."\n"
    )
end

local function _check_if_position_exists_and_is_empty(_input) -- Checks if the user has entered a valid position and that it is empty
    return board_data[_input] == " "
end

local function _check_win_condition(board,current_turn) --Checks if the current player has won
    for i = 1, 3 do --Firstly checks each row
        if board[location[i]..position[1]] == current_turn and board[location[i]..position[2]] == current_turn and board[location[i]..position[3]] == current_turn then
            return true --Then checks columns
        elseif board[location[1]..position[i]] == current_turn and board[location[2]..position[i]] == current_turn and board[location[3]..position[i]] == current_turn then
            return true 
        end -- Then checks diagonals
    if board[location[1]..position[1]] == current_turn and board[location[2]..position[2]] == current_turn and board[location[3]..position[3]] == current_turn then
        return true
    elseif board[location[3]..position[1]] == current_turn and board[location[2]..position[2]] == current_turn and board[location[1]..position[3]] == current_turn then
        return true
    end
    end
end

local function check_tie_condition(array)
    local is_not_empty = 0
    for i = 1,3 do
        if array[location[i]..position[1]] ~= " " and array[location[i]..position[2]] ~= " " and array[location[i]..position[3]] ~= " " then
            is_not_empty = is_not_empty + 3
        end
    end
    if is_not_empty == 9 then
        return true
    end
    return false
end

local function get_array_size(array)
    local count = 0
    for i in pairs(array) do
        count = count + 1
    end
    return count
end

local function find_empty_slots(board)
    local key_array = {"top_L","top_M","top_R","mid_L","mid_M","mid_R","low_L","low_M","low_R"}
    local empty_slots = {}
        for a in pairs(key_array) do
            if board[key_array[a]] == " " then
                table.insert(empty_slots,key_array[a])
            end
        end
    return empty_slots
end

local function minimax(board,current_player) -- MINIMAX ai
    local avaliable_slots = find_empty_slots(board)
    local size_of_array = get_array_size(avaliable_slots)

    if _check_win_condition(board,"X") then
        return {score = -1}
    elseif _check_win_condition(board,"O") then
        return {score = 1}
    elseif check_tie_condition(board) then
        return {score = 0}
    end

    local allTestPlayInfos = {}

    for i = 1, size_of_array do
        local currentTestPlayInfo = {}
        local index = avaliable_slots[i]
        board[index] = current_player
        if current_player == "O" then
            local x_result = minimax(board,"X")
            currentTestPlayInfo["score"] = x_result["score"]
        else
            local o_result = minimax(board,"O")
            currentTestPlayInfo["score"] = o_result["score"] --This line
        board[index] = " "
        currentTestPlayInfo["index"] = index
        table.insert(allTestPlayInfos,i,currentTestPlayInfo)
        end
        _draw_board()
    end
    local bestTestPlay = {}
    if current_player == "O" then
        local best_score = -700
        for i = 1, get_array_size(allTestPlayInfos) do
            if allTestPlayInfos[i]["score"] > best_score then
                best_score = allTestPlayInfos[i]["score"]
                bestTestPlay = i --allTestPlayInfos[i]["index"]
    else
        local best_score = 700
        for i = 1, get_array_size(allTestPlayInfos) do
            if allTestPlayInfos[i]["score"] < best_score then
                best_score = allTestPlayInfos[i]["score"]
                bestTestPlay = i --allTestPlayInfos[i]["index"]
            end
        end
    end
end
end
return allTestPlayInfos[bestTestPlay]
end

local function _game() --The main loop of the game
    local current_turn = "O" -- it holds two states X or O
    print("Please select a position from the board, to access the top row, type top_position position being L, M , R e.g top_L \n")
    _draw_board()
    while true do
        print("Player " ..current_turn.. " is selected!")
        if current_turn == "O" then -- Checks if its Os turn/AI and make it play the minimax function
            local play = minimax(board_data,"O")
            print(play)
            break
            --current_turn = "X"
        else -- Else its the players turn
            local Input = io.read()
        if _check_if_position_exists_and_is_empty(Input) then
            board_data[Input] = current_turn
            _draw_board()
            if _check_win_condition(board_data,current_turn) then
                print("Player "..current_turn .. " Has won this game!")
                break
            elseif check_tie_condition(board_data) then
                print("The game has ended at a tie!")
                break
            end
            if current_turn == "X" then -- Switch to the other player
                current_turn = "O"
            elseif current_turn == "O" then
                current_turn = "X"
            end
            
        else
            print("\nThat wasnt a command in the table or the slot wasnt empty!, example top_L, mid_R, low_M \n")
        end
    end
end
        end
        

_game()
```

edit:

```
local function minimax(board,current_player) -- MINIMAX ai
    local avaliable_slots = find_empty_slots(board)
    local size_of_array = get_array_size(avaliable_slots)

    if _check_win_condition(board,"X") then
        return {score = -1}
    elseif _check_win_condition(board,"O") then
        return {score = 1}
    elseif check_tie_condition(board) then
        return {score = 0}
    end

    local allTestPlayInfos = {}

    for i = 1, size_of_array do
        local currentTestPlayInfo = {}
        local index = avaliable_slots[i]
        board[index] = current_player
        if current_player == "O" then
            local x_result = minimax(board,"X")
            currentTestPlayInfo["score"] = x_result["score"]
        else
            local o_result = minimax(board,"O")
            currentTestPlayInfo["score"] = o_result["score"] --This line
        board[index] = " "
        currentTestPlayInfo["index"] = index
        table.insert(allTestPlayInfos,i,currentTestPlayInfo)
        end
    end
    local bestTestPlay = {}
    if current_player == "O" then
        local best_score = -700
        for i = 1, get_array_size(allTestPlayInfos) do
            if allTestPlayInfos[i]["score"] > best_score then
                best_score = allTestPlayInfos[i]["score"]
                bestTestPlay = i --allTestPlayInfos[i]["index"]
            end
        end
    else
        local best_score = 700
        for i = 1, get_array_size(allTestPlayInfos) do
            if allTestPlayInfos[i]["score"] < best_score then
                best_score = allTestPlayInfos[i]["score"]
                bestTestPlay = i --allTestPlayInfos[i]["index"]
            end
        end
    end
    return allTestPlayInfos[bestTestPlay]
end
```

I have fixed the ends (at least I think I have) and I still have it going out of bounds producing a nil value and I am not sure why, can someone please guide me, I would be grateful!

```
    for i = 1, size_of_array do
    local currentTestPlayInfo = {}
    local index = avaliable_slots[i]
    _draw_board() --This shows the board with one empty slot
    board[index] = current_player
    print(check_tie_condition(board)) -- THis returns true because its full
    _draw_board() -- draws the board and it is visually full as well
    if current_player == "O" then
        local x_result = minimax(board,"X") --This minimax function should be returning 0 since its full but it doesnt and I dont know why.
        currentTestPlayInfo["score"] = x_result["score"]
    else
        local o_result = minimax(board,"O")
        currentTestPlayInfo["score"] = o_result["score"] --Why does the score in the array get asigned a nil value it shouldnt be NIL!
    board[index] = " "
    currentTestPlayInfo["index"] = index
    table.insert(allTestPlayInfos,i,currentTestPlayInfo)
    end
```

This small bit of code is confusing me, the minimax reqursion doesnt return 0 since the board is full, why doesnt it return 0 like I told it to!

Comment: Your indentation appears to match the original code, but some `end`s are still in the wrong places. In blocks of code, JavaScript's `}` is roughly similar to Lua's `end`. You might have to learn a bit more about both languages to get it exactly right.

Comment: I understand a bit of the ends it's when I have to put things together is gets a bit confusing like one time I accidentally put some code in a for loop when it's supposed to be outside, anyways to make sure I understand its only the ends I am messing up here?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's just the main thing that stood out to me. I'm sure it's messing up your program logic, though. If you could get your text editor to auto-indent your code, you'll get a clearer idea of what your program is actually doing.

Comment: I am going to be honest nothing makes sense, the draw function for what ever reason doesnt activate and when the board is 6 slots full it stops printing and working all together, this REALLY doesnt make any sense on why its erroring out!

Comment: seeing your code I don't believe that you actually verified that your code does what it should do. so whatever you did, you didn't attack this problem correctly. you did not even bother to draw the board. otherwise you would have noticed that you're not stopping when the game is won.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is that you ask the player to pick a cell, but you start with the AI befor processing the players input.

Acutally debugging this is pretty trivial. All you need to do is to add a few debug prints where it makes sense.

I simply drew the board after each change and instantly noticed that you don't stop when the game is over.

You do not even stop when all cells are filled. This lead to an empty table available_slots. Then you return nil because the loop is not run. (I already told you this in your last post).

Which finally leads to indexing a nil value.

#### Edit:

I don't know why you keep mentioning that you move ends around. Your whole game logic is broken. Moving an end won't fix that.

This is what a few simple prints give you. Note how you ask the player for a turn but then let the AI begin...

```
Please select a position from the board, to access the top row, type top_position position being L, M , R e.g top_L 

 ┃ ┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 

Player O is selected!
called minimax, player  O
size of array   9
 ┃ ┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 

called minimax, player  X
size of array   8
O┃ ┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 

called minimax, player  O
size of array   7
O┃X┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 

called minimax, player  X
size of array   6
O┃X┃O
------
 ┃ ┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 

called minimax, player  O
size of array   5
O┃X┃O
------
X┃ ┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 

called minimax, player  X
size of array   4
O┃X┃O
------
X┃O┃ 
------
 ┃ ┃ 

called minimax, player  O
size of array   3
O┃X┃O
------
X┃O┃X
------
 ┃ ┃ 

called minimax, player  X
size of array   2
O┃X┃O
------
X┃O┃X
------
O┃ ┃ 

O wins
called minimax, player  X
size of array   1
O┃X┃O
------
X┃O┃X
------
O┃O┃ 

O wins
called minimax, player  X
size of array   0
O┃X┃O
------
X┃O┃X
------
O┃O┃O

O wins
lua: main.lua:99: attempt to index a nil value (local 'o_result')
```

You play one test game, you successfully detect the win condition. But after that you still play two more turns. Why are you continuing to run the for loop after the game is over?
That is nonsense and leads to the observed error.

Comment: OKAY, so it seems it was still an end issue, so moving the last 3 lines of code under the end has stop the error, now I have to figure out a way to stop it when it has reached the full board

Comment: Can you guide me, so from what understand, the loop needs to break when a condition is met,  but the condition at the beginning of the minimax function isn't going to stop this for loop, what should I do to figure this out. I should also mention the game function is in no way complete, at the moment I have it like so for testing purposes and I will refactoring until I get this minimax function working correctly

Comment: you're approaching this the wrong way. first design a solution, then translate it into Lua. all your mistakes can be easily avoided. instead of building a house from ground up following a plan you just made a pile of construction material and now desperately try to make something out of it. I can't make you think. you could for example break the for loop if minmax returns a number, but that might not fit to the rest of your code. so instead of trying to repair your code without even knowing what is going wrong think about a solution first. write it down in your native language then code

Comment: You are absolutely right, I really don't know what is wrong with it. It kinda works and kinda errors out a few test plays

Comment: Just one last thing, you mention the code has issues, is the minimax function all good? I say this because its the exactly the same as the freecodecamp website so I assume the person who made that code is good at coding, you said the for loop doesnt stop it should stop now, after I have made some changes link to code : https://pasteall.org/FLnM , somethings arent ready but it "works", so is the rest of my code not good and  if so can you tell me which ones, thank you.